# Linear Algebra One to one and onto function

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I was just wondering how I can tell if a function is onto.
$\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^1$
Lets say the standard transformation matrix has vectors $\{1,0,0\}$, $\{0,1,0\}$, $\{0,0,0\}$.
I know that this transformation is not one to one since they vectors are not linearly independent. How can I see if the transformation is onto?

Comment: i know but what if it's not one to one how can i test for onto

Comment: But there are cases in which a function is onto but not one to one

Comment: @user123204 Not for linear maps between vector spaces of the same dimension.

Comment: @MichaelKasa: Of the same finite dimension, to be precise.

Comment: it was supposed to be r^3 to r^1

Answer (score 2):

For a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, the following are equivalent:
(1) $T$ is one-one
(2) $T$ is onto
(3) If $T(v)=0$, then $v=0$

Generally, for a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, the following are equivalent:
(1) $T$ is onto
(2) There is some basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that the image of $T$ contains $\mathcal{B}$

Comment: if m<n then it is onto correct?

Comment: That's not guaranteed because a linear transformation can send everything to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to use the Rank-Nullity theorem whenever I can.

**The Rank Nullity Theorem.** Let $f:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Then 
$$
\operatorname{rk}f+\operatorname{nul}f=\dim V
$$
where $\operatorname{rk}f:=\dim\operatorname{im}f$ and $\operatorname{nul}f:=\dim\ker f$.

So, to check if a linear map $f:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is onto, we need only check that $\operatorname{nul}f=m-n$.

Comment: what if i only have a transformation matrix. In the problem I am solving, my transformation matrix from r3 to r1 is {23,2,0}. and since r1 falls into r3 if added two zeroes to the column, then i am assuming that my example is onto but not one-to-one?